# Where should the error checking go?

Tags: excel, vba

So this might be a really dumb question, but I am combing through this code and I need to check if Cells (A5, A7, A10) are empty I would like to pop up a messagebox that explains that these fields must be filled before continuing.  Here is the entire code block. I just can't figure out where to place the error check. Any help would be wonderful. Thanks!

```
'Set Variables
Products = Range("B1") + 3 'Number of Products on Sheet
Count = 4 'Count Used to Change the Active Cell

Do While Count <= Products
    'Checks if Product is Add On Only
    If Cells(Count, 17) = "yes" Then
        If Cells(Count, 5) = "grouped" Or Cells(Count, 5) = "configurable" Then
            'Adds the **ADD ON ONLY** and Combines the Cells to Create Main Title
            Cells(Count, 7) = Trim("** ADD ON ONLY** " & Cells(Count, 2) & " " & Cells(Count, 3) & " " & Cells(Count, 6))
            'Copies Main Title To Short Description & Image Labels
            Cells(Count, 37) = Cells(Count, 7)
            'Checks if product is Child Configurable
            If Cells(Count, 4) <> "simple - child config" Then
                'Adds Main Title to Image Labels when Product is not Child Config
                Cells(Count, 56) = Cells(Count, 7)
                Cells(Count, 58) = Cells(Count, 7)
                Cells(Count, 60) = Cells(Count, 7)
            End If

         Else
            'Adds the **ADD ON ONLY** and Combines the Cells to Create Main Title
            Cells(Count, 7) = Trim("** ADD ON ONLY** " & Cells(Count, 2) & " " & Cells(Count, 3) & " " & Cells(Count, 6) & " " & Cells(Count, 24))
            'Copies Main Title To Short Description & Image Labels
            Cells(Count, 37) = Cells(Count, 7)
            'Checks if product is Child Configurable
            If Cells(Count, 5) <> "simple - child config" Then
                'Adds Main Title to Image Labels when Product is not Child Config
                Cells(Count, 56) = Cells(Count, 7)
                Cells(Count, 58) = Cells(Count, 7)
                Cells(Count, 60) = Cells(Count, 7)
            End If
        End If

    'If Product Is NOT Add On Only
    Else
        If Cells(Count, 5) = "grouped" Or Cells(Count, 5) = "configurable" Then
             'Adds Combines the Cells to Create Main Title
            Cells(Count, 7) = Trim(Cells(Count, 2) & " " & Cells(Count, 3) & " " & Cells(Count, 6))
            'Copies Main Title To Short Description & Image Labels
            Cells(Count, 37) = Cells(Count, 7)
             'Checks if product is Child Configurable
            If Cells(Count, 5) <> "simple - child config" Then
                'Adds Main Title to Image Labels when Product is not Child Config
                Cells(Count, 56) = Cells(Count, 7)
                Cells(Count, 58) = Cells(Count, 7)
                Cells(Count, 60) = Cells(Count, 7)
            End If
        Else
            'Adds Combines the Cells to Create Main Title
            Cells(Count, 7) = Trim(Cells(Count, 2) & " " & Cells(Count, 3) & " " & Cells(Count, 6) & " " & Cells(Count, 24))
            'Copies Main Title To Short Description & Image Labels
            Cells(Count, 37) = Cells(Count, 7)
             'Checks if product is Child Configurable
            If Cells(Count, 5) <> "simple - child config" Then
                'Adds Main Title to Image Labels when Product is not Child Config
                Cells(Count, 56) = Cells(Count, 7)
                Cells(Count, 58) = Cells(Count, 7)
                Cells(Count, 60) = Cells(Count, 7)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    'Performs Actions on Next Cell Range

     Count = Count + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: A5, A7, A10 sound specific.  Do you really need to execute the do while loop if those cells are empty?  If cells are empty then don't execute do loop otherwise the loop will be executed.

Comment: I cannot see a single reference to not only A%, A7 or A10 let alone any reference to a cell in column A. Put your error check at the very top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cells (A5, A7, A10) are empty I would like to pop up a messagebox that explains that these fields must be filled before continuing.

In that case, I would add up at the top.

```
If IsEmpty(Range("A5").Value) And IsEmpty(Range("A7").Value) And IsEmpty(Range("A10").Value) Then
    MsgBox ("Please fill in A5, A7, and A10 - then rerun the macro.")
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful